# US Government API Usage

Tags: data-request, usa, government, api

I'm unable to find very much data about the usage of APIs from United States federal agencies. Which APIs that have been released have the highest traffic number in terms of queries, and/or implementation?

Comment: Number of queries?  So a poorly designed API that makes you send 100 REST calls vs. one SOAP call is therefore 'higher traffic' ?

Comment: Data.gov has some data related to [visitor stats](http://www.data.gov/metric/visitorstats/dailyvisitorstatistics) though I haven't explored the other sections extensively (e.g. [Downloads by Data Category](http://www.data.gov/metric/visitorstats/monthlyredirectbydatacategory)) some of the sources might point you in the right direction for API-related metrics.

Comment: Did someone just make a case for SOAP? Epic!

Comment: Have you thought about FOIA'ing this data?

Comment: @noneck I have FOIAd for this data. Never successfully.

Comment: I've successfully FOIAd web traffic stats from the State Department, but haven't tried others. There's no reason why you couldn't FOIA the server logs.

Comment: @dwillis correct. I FOIAd the FCC for server logs. They wanted me to pay per-page for the printout of the logs. Because it wasn't high priority for me, I just let it lie and didn't push it. FOIA-ing for this stuff, when they have no idea how to deliver it just seems weird to me.

Answer (score 2):

There is a growing catalog of APIs from the federal government available at Data.gov's [Developer community](http://www.data.gov/developers/page/developer-resources).  Activity on each dataset will be made visible in the activity stream area (not yet visible as the [new catalog](http://catalog.data.gov/dataset) was just created last week).  In the meantime, you can see API activity as follows:

- EPA Envirofacts API: [dataset page](http://catalog.data.gov/dataset/epa-envirofacts-api) and [activity stream](http://catalog.data.gov/dataset/activity/epa-envirofacts-api)
- [Previous metrics](https://explore.data.gov/Geography-and-Environment/EPA-Envirofacts-API/ctg5-dfaz) (temporary solution) until the activity streams are populated

(Disclaimer: I am the Evangelist for Data.gov.)